# Does Java JDBI `SqlQuery` have idiomatic support for SQL `=` AND SQL `IS NULL` with one expression?

Tags: java, sql, jdbi

Let's take a simple `SELECT` query:

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE some_column = :myVar")
List<MyObjects> getBySomeColumn(String myVar);
```

I'd like to know if there is something like the above, but handles both `IS NULL` and `=` similarly, automatically:

```
@SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE some_column <MAGIC_HERE> :myVar")
List<MyObjects> getBySomeColumn(String myVar);
```

... which would run either:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE some_column IS NULL
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE some_column = :myVar
```

... depending on whether `myVar` is `null` or not. What is the most idiomatic way to handle this kind of query?

Comment: In standard SQL you could use `where some_column is not distinct from :myVar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

1. Rewrite SQL query to something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE (:myVar is null and some_column is null) or some_column = :myVar
```

2. Use JDBI [templating](http://jdbi.org/#_templating) to dynamically rewrite queries